# Powershell replace multiline doesn't work when matching end of line

Tags: powershell-core

I have a problem when replacing a multi line string with the MultiLine option.

I'd expect the following snippet:

```
@"
abc
---
def
"@ -replace '(?m)^---$', 'AAA'
```

to result in:

```
abc
AAA
def
```

whereas it outputs:

```
abc
---
def
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: It works on my machine (Windows 11). Can you try removing the start and end chars (^ and $)?

Comment: Can you please provide a hex representation of the text with `$text | Format-Hex`? Seems the line ending (CRLF) are the problem. Quick fix: `(?m)^---\r?$`

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. There were `\r\n` line endings and `$` matched only `\n`. The solution by @swbbl worked, or removing `\r` first (e.g. `$text = $text -replace "``r``n", "``n"`)

Comment: @swbbl Can you please post it as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of line/string token `$` of regex can't match the end of line in [regex' multiline mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-multiline) when CRLF (carriage return <sup>0x0D</sup> + line feed <sup>0x0A</sup>) is used for line breaks.

**Info:** This is not the case in non-multiline mode where `$` matches the end of string.

For files which are using CRLF as line endings *(which is the default behavior of Windows)* it's necessary to use `\r$`, but to be entirely compatible with any file and operating system (like unix/linux, where LF is used), the carriage return should be made optional: `\r?$`

---

With PowerShell it's also easily possible to figure out which line endings are in place. The character hex code `0D` followed by `0A` means CRLF.
Example:

```powershell
@'
TEST
123
'@ | Format-Hex

#returns:
#
#   Label: String (System.String) <7AFCD388>
#
#           Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
#                  00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
#           ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
# 0000000000000000 54 45 53 54 0D 0A 31 32 33                      TEST��123
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiline mode also for the new line:

```
@"
abc
---
def
"@ -replace '(?m)^---(?m)$', 'AAA'
```